# Objective C Read String with White Spaces

Tags: objective-c, whitespace, scanf

I have the following code, but can't get it to display the name at all.
If I have `scanf("%s", inputBuffer);` i get only the first word. It Breaks at the whitespace. So I changed it to `scanf("%[\n]", inputBuffer);` but still does not work. Any help please...

```
> int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int number;
    double payRate, hours, totalPay;
    NSString *name;
    char inputBuffer[200];


    NSLog (@"Enter the number of entries to be processed: ");
    scanf ("%i", &number);

    for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++){
        NSLog (@"Enter the name:");
        scanf("%[\n]", inputBuffer);
        name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:inputBuffer];

        NSLog(@"Name: %@", name);
        NSLog(@"Hours:%.2lf", hours);
        NSLog(@"Pay Rate:%.2lf",payRate);
        NSLog(@"Total Pay:%.2lf", totalPay);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", inputBuffer);
```